# How can I teleport one player to a random other player using a potion as the trigger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a Minecraft map. I want to make it that when someone uses a certain potion, that same person teleports to a random user on the map.

I can't use the `@p` thing because the other players might teleport instead.  I know to use the `/effect` code on command blocks and some other commands.

Comment: I've been working on this for probably an hour now. Maybe longer, I've lost track. I've solved the issue of specifying the first player using `@p[c=n]`, the problem I'm running into now is the "random other player" part, since `/tp Unionhawk Unionhawk` is valid.

Comment: I'm trying it using experience as an identifier, however, it is only possible to identify players who are *inside* a certain level range, and cannot identify players who are *not* a specified level, except at level 0.

Answer (score 3):

This was a very interesting challenge for me to work out. There are many parts to this problem, which are a lot harder to accomplish than one might think. There's identifying the player with the status effect, and identifying a set of random players who are not them (since `/tp Unionhawk Unionhawk` is a valid result of `/tp @p @r`, and does nothing).

But, finally, here is my setup, which works for a bounded number of players on a server. Some of its flaws include only allowing one game to be played on a given server, and using experience level to identify players. As such, `/gamerule doMobLoot false` must be used, and `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false` is strongly advised.

[image]

So there's quite a lot of things going on here, as you can see. But this is all accomplished using 4 commands and a hopper clock.

The Group 1 command blocks are there to detect when a player has the specified potion effect, remove it, and proceed to the matching Group 2 command block. I used `/effect @p[c=n] 4 0` for that one, which removes the mining fatigue effect from player n on the server (going down the list of players on the server). When that command evaluates, the Group 2 command blocks give that player one level of experience using `/xp 1L @p[c=n]`.

From there, the next time the hopper clock pulses, the "Group" 3 (you only need one) command block teleports a player with 1 level or more to a random player without any levels using `/tp @p[lm=1] @r[l=0]`. When this command evaluates, the "Group" 4 command block clears the experience level of all players using `/xp -9999L @a`.

Answer (score -3):

All you have to do is (no potions) do `/give [your username] 137 1`, that gets you a command block. Put this in the command block: `/tp @p -522 9 -434`

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.